# Remove 1 field from json

Tags: java, json, algorithm, recursion, jackson

I would like to test a rest api and check if all fields of a json request are mandatory.
I have the full json request with all mandatory fields set, and I would like to get all requests with 1 of the mandatory fields missing.

for instance, I have this request:

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": {
    "c": [1, 2, 3],
    "d": "d"
  },
  "e": [{"f": 1, "g": 2}]
}
```

I would like to test theses json requests to see if all fail as expected:

```
{
  "b": {
    "c": [1, 2, 3],
    "d": "d"
  },
  "e": [{"f": 1, "g": 2}]
}
```

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "e": [{"f": 1, "g": 2}]
}
```

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": {
    "d": "d"
  },
  "e": [{"f": 1, "g": 2}]
}
```

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": {
    "c": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  "e": [{"f": 1, "g": 2}]
}
```

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": {
    "c": [1, 2, 3],
    "d": "d"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": {
    "c": [1, 2, 3],
    "d": "d"
  },
  "e": [{"g": 2}]
}
```

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": {
    "c": [1, 2, 3],
    "d": "d"
  },
  "e": [{"f": 1}]
}
```

The json is recursively composed of values, objects and arrays.
I tried some recursive method to return all requests, each one with 1 missing node, but I am facing some troubles with arrays.
Here what I did:

```
    public static List<JsonNode> toto(Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> jsonNodeEntry) {
        List<JsonNode> list = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonNodeEntry.getValue();
        if(jsonNode.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode jsonObject = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> elements = jsonNode.fields();
            while (elements.hasNext()) {
                for (JsonNode subJsonNode: toto(elements.next())) {
                    list.add(jsonObject.deepCopy().set(jsonNodeEntry.getKey(), subJsonNode));
                }
                ObjectNode jsonObjectCopy = jsonObject.deepCopy();
                jsonObjectCopy.remove(jsonNodeEntry.getKey());
                list.add(jsonObjectCopy);
            }
        }
        if(jsonNode.isArray()) {
            for(JsonNode toto : (ArrayNode)jsonNode) {
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> subIterator = toto.fields();
                while (subIterator.hasNext()) {
                    for (JsonNode subJsonNode: toto(subIterator.next())) {
                        //list.add(toto.deepCopy().set(jsonNodeEntry.getKey(), subJsonNode));
                    }
                    //list.add(jsonNode.deepCopy().remove(jsonNodeEntry.getKey()));
                }
            }
        }
       // list.add(jsonNode.deepCopy().remove(jsonNodeEntry.getKey()));
        return list;
    }

    public static List<String> getJsonRequestsWithOneMandatoryFieldMissing(String jsonStringFromFile) throws IOException {
        String jsonString = jsonStringFromFile.replace("#now", ValuesTests.NOW.convert());
        List<String> jsonResquestsWithoutOneMandatoryField = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode mandatoryFields = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jsonString);
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = mandatoryFields.fields();
        while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> jsonNodeEntry = fieldsIterator.next();
            if(jsonNodeEntry.getValue().isObject()) {
                ObjectNode jsonObject = (ObjectNode) jsonNodeEntry.getValue();
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> elements = jsonNodeEntry.getValue().fields();
                while (elements.hasNext()) {
                    for (JsonNode jsonNode: toto(elements.next())) {
                        jsonResquestsWithoutOneMandatoryField.add(mandatoryFields.deepCopy().set(jsonNodeEntry.getKey(), jsonNode).toPrettyString());
                    }
                    ObjectNode mandatoryFieldsCopy = mandatoryFields.deepCopy();
                    mandatoryFieldsCopy.remove(jsonNodeEntry.getKey());
                    jsonResquestsWithoutOneMandatoryField.add(mandatoryFieldsCopy.toPrettyString());
                }
            }
            if(jsonNodeEntry.getValue().isArray()) {
                for(JsonNode toto : (ArrayNode)(jsonNodeEntry.getValue())) {
                    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> subIterator = toto.fields();
                    while (subIterator.hasNext()) {
                        for (JsonNode jsonNode: toto(subIterator.next())) {
                            jsonResquestsWithoutOneMandatoryField.add(mandatoryFields.deepCopy().set(jsonNodeEntry.getKey(), jsonNode).toPrettyString());
                        }
                        ObjectNode mandatoryFieldsCopy = mandatoryFields.deepCopy();
                        mandatoryFieldsCopy.remove(jsonNodeEntry.getKey());
                        jsonResquestsWithoutOneMandatoryField.add(mandatoryFieldsCopy.toPrettyString());
                    }
                }
            }
            ObjectNode mandatoryFieldsCopy = mandatoryFields.deepCopy();
            mandatoryFieldsCopy.remove(jsonNodeEntry.getKey());
            jsonResquestsWithoutOneMandatoryField.add(mandatoryFieldsCopy.toPrettyString());
        }
        return jsonResquestsWithoutOneMandatoryField;
    }
```

I really don't know how to get the last requests when the jsonNode is a JsonArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it:

```
    public static List<JsonNode> recursiveJsonParser(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        List<JsonNode> listToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        if(jsonNode.isValueNode()) {
        }
        if(jsonNode.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = objectNode.fields();
            while (fields.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> current = fields.next();
                List<JsonNode> subList = recursiveJsonParser(current.getValue());
                for (JsonNode subJsonNode: subList) {
                    ObjectNode objectNodeCopy = objectNode.deepCopy();
                    objectNodeCopy.set(current.getKey(), subJsonNode);
                    listToReturn.add(objectNodeCopy);
                }
            }
        }
        if(jsonNode.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) jsonNode;
            Iterator<JsonNode> elements = arrayNode.elements();
            while (elements.hasNext()) {
                int index = 0;
                List<JsonNode> subList = recursiveJsonParser(elements.next());
                for (JsonNode subJsonNode: subList) {
                    ArrayNode arrayNodeCopy = arrayNode.deepCopy();
                    arrayNodeCopy.set(index, subJsonNode);
                    listToReturn.add(arrayNodeCopy);
                }
                index ++;
            }
        }
        listToReturn.add(NullNode.getInstance());
        return listToReturn;
    }
```

Simpler is better!